# Rendering Webkit into GL texture

Tags: opengl, webkit

I'm looking for a portable, as-less-hackish-as-possible way of rendering WebKit into texture, and injecting events back into texture. Bonus points for being able to override theme of UI elements (textboxes, buttons, scrollbars). Extra bonus points for being able to render into SDL surface as well. Overall, I'd like to be able to just grab a RGBA pixel byte array and do with it as I please. Browser shouldn't be running, it should all be done in-game.

This should in no way be platform dependent and should be compatible with developing both proprietary and DFGS-free software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/) is an open source (BSD) project designed to do this, but I don't have any personal experience with it.

**Edit October 2013:**

I still seem to be getting the occasional upvote for this answer, although as mentioned in the comments bellow Berkelium does seem to be pretty much abandoned (I know I vaguely defend it against that accusation in the comments, but realistically it is true).

I've read some encouraging things recently about [Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) and would suggest the dear reader may want to check that out, as well as [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076327/offscreen-embeddable-browsers-comparison-for-use-in-a-game).

[Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) is also well worth a mention. Not being FOSS might be a deal-breaker for some, but it is free to use if your revenue is <$100k.

Comment: Berkelium looks awesome! Thank you so much! Here's a link to a demo (for other readers): https://github.com/sirikata/berkelium/blob/chromium8/demo/glut_input/glut_input.cpp

Comment: There're commits as recently as 6 months ago on github and it seems that when questions occasionally come either as github issues or on the google group the author still responds promptly (last activity on the Google group was in June). Clearly not particularly active development nor massively used, but I don't think it's fair to call it abandoned. Maybe just stable :) I don't know, I've still never actually used it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/) does what you are asking for. It is free for non-commercial use. But be forewarned, previous versions of the project had some serious bugs and performance issues. Try before you buy.

Comment: My apologies for not making myself clear. I do not use Windows and therefore I also don't use Visual Studio. Since I'm switching platforms very often, and since I support and develop both free software and proprietary software, this should be preferably both cross-platform and free (BSD/LGPL). While I know about Awesomium from back when it was announced on Webkit-Meta mailing list, I didn't know it went commercial.